# Angular 4 app after deployment does not work

Tags: angular

I'm building an angular app which works fine when I do ng serve on the local machine.  But after deploying the app on firebase it causes an error.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for e! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for e!
at k (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1)
at E (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1)
at t._throwOrNull (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1)
at t._getByKeyDefault (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1)
at t._getByKey (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1)
at t.get (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1)
at qe (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1)
at t.get (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1)
at Sn (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1)
at kn (vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1) Error: No provider for e!
at k (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:4823)
at E (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:5050)
at t._throwOrNull (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:72085)
at t._getByKeyDefault (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:72418)
at t._getByKey (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:71803)
at t.get (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:70211)
at qe (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:22155)
at t.get (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:120927)
at Sn (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:28914)
at kn (https://lottery-management-system.firebaseapp.com/vendor.e0a9c104ecc1b06ef61f.bundle.js:1:27420)
```

I went through the app and looked for all the promises that were being made and commented them out and still it is giving me the error.

Because of minification of the code it's hard to trace what's going on. 
Is there an easier way to debug an error when the code has been minified? Also what could be causing this error?

Thanks for the help!

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MdButtonModule, MdCardModule, MdMenuModule, MdToolbarModule, 
          MdTabsModule, MdIconModule, MdSidenavModule,
          MdInputModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdTooltipModule, MdGridListModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';
import { BookComponent } from './book/book.component';
import { ShiftComponent } from './shift/shift.component';
import { ScanComponent } from './scan/scan.component';
import { Settings } from './settings/settings';
import { SettingsService } from './services/settings.service';
import { Book } from './book/book';
import { BookService } from './services/book.service';
import { ShiftService } from './services/shift.service';
import { Shift } from './shift/shift';
import { ScanService } from './services/scan.service';
import { ScanTicket } from './scan/scan-ticket';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { User } from './user/user';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { AuthRequestOptions } from './guards/auth-request';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthErrorHandler } from './guards/auth-error-handler';
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './guards/auth.interceptor';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    BookComponent,
    ShiftComponent,
    ScanComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MdButtonModule, 
    MdCardModule, 
    MdMenuModule, 
    MdToolbarModule, 
    MdIconModule,
    MdSidenavModule,
    MdTabsModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdTooltipModule,
    MdGridListModule,
    routes
  ],
  providers: [User, AuthGuard, AuthService, Settings, SettingsService, BookService, Book, ShiftService, Shift, ScanService, ScanTicket,
    // {
    //   provide: RequestOptions, 
    //   useClass: AuthRequestOptions
    // }, 
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler, 
      useClass: AuthErrorHandler
    }, 
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: this is related to some wrong configuration of `node_modules` in production mode. any errors while aot build?

Comment: No errors while compiling.  The app works fine on the local machine when I do ng serve.

Comment: If you do an `ng serve --prod` on your local machine, do you see the same errors? Also, you can still generate map files and see your unminified code using a command line switch on the build.

Comment: when you are doing a prod build without minification what error you are getting? are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: After doing `ng serve --prod` on the local machine, it did cause the same errors.

Comment: Please edit your question with your app.module.ts listing.

Comment: Just posted the app.module.ts

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303021/angular-4-4-0-4-4-2-production-build-throwing-no-provider-for-ngform-error

Answer (score 0):

The above problem was being caused by Angular 4.4.3 thanks @yurzui for pointing that problem out.  The issue is related to a file Zone.js.  I was able to figure that out by unabling the `--sourcemaps  true` in the build thanks to @DeborahK

The problem went a way after I upgraded to angular 5.0.0